# java scanner and patterns

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to the scanner method.  Is there a way to check if the scanner.nextLine() contains a pattern?

For example xxx. xxxx: xxxx. xxxx:

So I want to check that there is a . : . : ignoring the xxxx in between.  The xxxx can represent any primitive type of String.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I usually use Scanner for simple parsing of lines and use regex / `String#split(...)` for more detailed parsing. Myself, I'd just get the line with the Scanner and then split the String.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Its more to check then for splitting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [findInLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine(java.util.regex.Pattern)) method

> Attempts to find the next occurrence of the specified pattern ignoring
>   delimiters. If the pattern is found before the next line separator,
>   the scanner advances past the input that matched and returns the
>   string that matched the pattern. If no such pattern is detected in the
>   input up to the next line separator, then null is returned and the
>   scanner's position is unchanged. This method may block waiting for
>   input that matches the pattern.